# Remap arrow keys to move directory in NERDTree

Tags: vim, nerdtree

When using NERDTree, I would like to remap the left and right arrow to move up and down a directory.

I believe the left arrow has to be mapped to 'u' but I do not know how to do this only when NERDTree is the active window.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
autocmd FileType nerdtree nmap <buffer> <left> u
```